# How to use TimerTask with lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, abstract-class, timertask, java-8

As you hopefully know you can use lambdas in Java 8, for example to replace anonymous methods.

An example can be seen here of Java 7 vs Java 8:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkDirectory();
    }
};
```

Can be expressed as both the following ways in Java 8:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> checkDirectory();
```

or

```
Runnable runnable = this::checkDirectory;
```

This is because `Runnable` is a functional interface, having only one (abstract) public non-default method.

However... For `TimerTask` we have the following:

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkDirectory();
    }
};
```

Looks familiar, right?
Using a lambda expression does not work though, because `TimerTask` is an abstract class, even though it has only one abstract public non-default method, it is not an interface and hence no functional interface either.
It is also not refactored into an interface with default implementations, because it carries state, so that cannot be done then.

So my **question**: Is there any way to use lambdas when constructing the `TimerTask`?

What I wanted is the following:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(this::checkDirectory, 0, 1 * 1000);
```

Instead of some ugly anonymous inner class, is there any way to make it nicer?

Comment: Since you use modern features, why not go all the way and use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of a `TimerTask`? ;)

Comment: @fge Well, I didn't know it existed, until now... Now I think about it, does Java not have their APIs mention that there is a newer similar feature available, when the old feature is not yet *deprecated*?

Comment: In case of `Timer`, Josh Bloch's Effective Java 2nd Edition advises that. It is not an official position of the JDK API, though.

Comment: Eh, no... This is admittedly a great lack in their documentation. Similarly, they don't mention `Files` in the `File` doc;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Noting first that `Timer` is effectively an antiquated API, but entertaining your question nevertheless, you could write a small wrapper around it which would adapt the `schedule` method to accept a `Runnable`, and on the inside you'd turn that `Runnable` into a `TimerTask`. Then you would have your `schedule` method which would accept a lambda.

```
public class MyTimer {
  private final Timer t = new Timer();

  public TimerTask schedule(final Runnable r, long delay) {
     final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() { public void run() { r.run(); }};
     t.schedule(task, delay);
     return task;
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically your answer is correct, however I will personally go with `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of `TimerTask`.

Comment: what's the current API then?

Answer (score 1):

To complete Marko Topolnik's answer about `Timer`, you just have to call `schedule` method with a lambda.

```
schedule(() -> {
    System.out.println("Task #1 is running");
}, 500);
```

Comment: `Runnable` is an interface,  you can implement it with a lambda. So you can call the `schedule` method with a lambda. Here is a working gist https://gist.github.com/fsamin/ec5aa79bc23965eca277

Comment: Misunderstood answer; you're entirely correct of course.

Answer (score 1):

While Marko's answer is perfectly correct, I prefer my implementation:

```
public class FunctionalTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    Runnable task;

    public FunctionalTimerTask(Runnable task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        task.run();
    }
}

 public static class Task {
    public static TimerTask set(Runnable run) {
        return new FunctionalTimerTask(() -> System.err.println("task"));
    }
}

 Timer timer = new Timer(false);
 timer.schedule(Task.set(() -> doStuff()), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
```

This gives you more control over the timer, and you have a static utility class. Idealy give it a name that won't conflict with other common thread class, so not Task, Job, Timer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for completeness, I wanted to include the [wrapper solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971251/236365) posted by [Flown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4105457/flown):

```
private static TimerTask wrap(Runnable r) {
  return new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      r.run();
    }
  };
}
```

then your call can become:

```
timer.schedule(wrap(this::checkDirectory), delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use a scheduler:

```
  ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  Future<?> timeout = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::checkDirectory, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

runs `checkDirectory` each second.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a Timer easily with lambdas from the Swing API if you want (but not with TimerTask) :

`new javax.swing.Timer(1000, (ae) -> this::checkDirectory).start();`