# Passing lambda to a Timer instead of TimerTask

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to perform a delayed operation on a map, so I am using `Timer`, to which I am passing a `TimerTask` and a delay in milliseconds:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        tournaments.remove(id);
    }
}, delay);
```

This is some sort of primitive cache-like functionality where I set an expiration time on a new resource that was just created.

I thought I could do that using lambdas, just like follows:

```
times.schedule(() -> tournaments.remove(id), delay);
```

But the compiler says this cannot be done. Why? What am I doing wrong? Could I use lambdas to achieve more concise code or it's simply not possible here and I should stick to an anonymous class?

Comment: What does the compiler tell you? Also, you're missing the second `delay` parameter in your example.

Comment: It says *"cannot resolve method schedule(<lambda expression>, long)"*

Comment: You should use `ScheduledExecutorService` in preference to `Timer`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482093/why-cant-functionalinterface-be-applied-to-a-sam-abstract-base-class/31491773#31491773

Comment: @Zircon you're absolutely wrong. Have a look at this notation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date) . The real problem is that TimerTask is not a functional interface, or an interface at all, so it can not be expressed via lambda

Comment: @Ben this question is 2 years old...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`TimerTask` is not a SAM (single abstract method) type -- now, that sounds contradictory, because there is only one abstract method on TimerTask! But because the abstract parent class implements `cancel` and `scheduledExecutionTime`, even though they're not abstract, the compiler can't go so far as to take your lambda and create an anonymous subtype of `TimerTask`.

What can be done is lambdas for interfaces that have a single abstract method and one or more *default* methods, but sadly TimerTask is an older class and doesn't use the default method capabilities of Java 8.

Comment: Any other "modern" alternative for setting timers that would be as concise as what I am trying to get to?

Comment: The term you're looking for is _functional interface_.

Comment: @BrianGoetz ah, did that totally supercede the "SAM" nomenclature? I guess I'm out of date.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thank you, I wish I had that technical and terminological knowledge. I will try out `ScheduledExecutorService` as you suggested in your other comment.

Comment: @TomG Yes.  We started with the idea of SAM types, there was an extensive debate within the Expert Group as to whether to support SAM abstract types (notably, TimerTask is really the only example that ever seems to comes up!), and after a lot of discussion, we concluded that supporting SAM abstract types introduced too much semantic complexity to carry its weight.  Hence was born the term "functional interface".

Comment: This has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31482093/2711488) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24610207/2711488).

Comment: In other words Java compiler writers are lazy again.

Answer (score 28):

In order to use lambda expression you need a target type which has to be a SAM type, i.e. functional interface. Since `TimerTask` is an abstract class you can't use lambdas here.
What you can do, to use lambda expressions, is to write an utility function which wraps your code into a `TimerTask` like:

```
private static TimerTask wrap(Runnable r) {
  return new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      r.run();
    }
  };
}
```

Then you can use your lambda:

```
times.schedule(wrap(() -> tournaments.remove(id)), delay);
```

Comment: although I liked the solution, it seems less readable