# Discord bot changing status activity every 30 seconds jda

Tags: java, discord-jda

I would like to make the bot refresh/change status (Activity)for two different messages every 30 seconds

```
jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing("message1"));
jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing("message2"));
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I would like the bot to refresh the status (activity) every 30 seconds, 
Every refresh changes to a different message. (message1, message2)

Comment: Just use a Timer?

Comment: Could you please help me how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to create an array with the messages and an index that alternates between 0 and the last message:

```java
String[] messages={"message 1","message 2"};
int currentIndex=0;
```

Every 30 seconds, you can then execute the following:

```java
jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing(messages[currentIndex]));
currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%messages.length;
```

This [sets the `Activity` to the current message](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/managers/Presence.html#setActivity(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity)) (element in the array of `currentIndex`) at first.

After this, it adds `1` to `currentIndex`.

If `currentIndex` exceeds the array length, it sets it to `0`, again. This is done using the [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

In order to execute that every 30 seconds, you can use one of the following methods:

### java.util.Timer

The old method for doing this is by creating a `Timer`:

```java
//Outside of any method
private String[] messages={"message 1","message 2"};
private int currentIndex=0;
//Run this once
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
  public void run(){
    jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing(messages[currentIndex]));
    currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%messages.length;
  }},0,30_000);
```

[`Timer#schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,long,long)) can execute a `TimerTask` after a specific delay (0 as you want to start rightaway) and let it repeat after a specified period (both the delay and the period are in milliseconds).

### java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService

It is also possible to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` that allows for more customization (this method is considered "better" than `Timer` as e.g. stated in Java Concurrency in Practice, Chapter 6.2.5):

```java
//outside of any method
private String[] messages = { "message 1", "message 2" };
private int currentIndex = 0;
private ScheduledExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
//run this once
threadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
    jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing(messages[currentIndex]));
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % messages.length;
}, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//when you want to stop it (e.g. when the bot is stopped)
threadPool.shutdown();
```

At first, a thread pool is created that allows scheduling of tasks.

This thread pool could also be used for other tasks.

In this example, this is done using a single thread. If you want to use multiple threads, you can use `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(numberOfThreads);`.

After this, you call [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) what runs the provided `Runnable` every 30 seconds.

If you want it to automatically stop when the application stops without calling `shutdown()`, you can tell it to use daemon threads by specifying the `ThreadFactory`:

```java
ScheduledExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(r->{
    Thread t=new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t;
});
```

Comment: Where should I give message 2?

Comment: [linkerror](https://i.imgur.com/llMoVo6.png) what should i do?

Comment: Did you import `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: Yes is imported import java.util.Timer;

Comment: I forgot that `TimerTask` [is not a SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37970821/10871900). Doed my edit work?